# Learn how to develop open source applications with many developers

Tags: version-control, open-source, github, collaboration

I'm a solo developer and always have been, but I've been learning lately about the possibilities of source control and project collaboration. I would really like to learn how to work with large groups of developers (say on github). I think it would be an amazing learning experience, but up till now I have always been the only developer on a given project. Are there any recourses for learning how to work on small portions of a project to get bits done? Books? Examples? I know I have to start somewhere, but I'm not sure how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join an open source project.

Find something on GitHub or another large open source project repository using a language you like and/or a project that fires your imagination.

Read the wiki/mailing lists and find out how to contribute.

In this case, the best way to learn is to do.

Comment: Would you recommend a smaller project for getting started then? I'm worried about not being able to comprehend a project that has already been in development long before I start adding to it. Usually if I spend enough time reading through the source I can understand the way it works, but I'm not sure I could handle working on something really large without understanding how everything functions together. Is that something that you just get used to?

Comment: @Lance - Not particularly. You never grasp large code bases in one go, you learn them in small parts and by working on different portions. Large projects are more likely to have small bits of work required that will ease you in.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I appreciate your help. I guess I'm going to have to just pick something and try it.

Comment: @Lance - Good luck. Enjoy and learn :)